# Incompatible types in assignment char ** to char *

Tags: c++, c

I have the following bit of code:

As a global variable:

```
char *orderFiles[10];
```

And then my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    orderFiles = argv;
}
```

However it keeps giving me an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should retag this as C, not C++, btw.

Comment: Tagged it C as well since it applies to _both_ languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you an error because `char *x[10]` gives you an array of ten char pointers which is non-modifiable. In other words, you cannot assign to `x`, nor change it in any way. The equivalent *changeable* version would be `char **orderFiles` - you can assign `argv` to that just fine.

As an aside, you *could* transfer individual arguments to your array thus:

```
for (i = 0; i <= argc && i < sizeof(orderFiles)/(sizeof(*orderFiles); i++)
    orderFiles[i] = argv[i];
```

but that seems rather convoluted. It will either fill up `orderFiles` with the first `N` arguments or partially fill it, making the next one NULL.

If your intent is simply to stash away the arguments into a global so that you can reference them anywhere, you should do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **orderFiles;
int orderCount;

static void someFn (void) {
    int i;
    printf ("Count = %d\n", orderCount);
    for (i = 0; i < orderCount; i++)
        printf ("%3d: [%s]\n", i, orderFiles[i]);
    // or, without orderCount:
    //    for (i = 0; orderFiles[i] != NULL; i++)
    //        printf ("%3d: [%s]\n", i, orderFiles[i]);
    //    printf ("Count was %d\n", i);

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    orderCount = argc;
    orderFiles = argv;
    someFn();
    return 0;
}
```

That code saves the arguments into globals so they can be accessed in a different function.

You should save both arguments to `main` if you want to use `argc` as well although, technically, it's not necessary since `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be NULL for hosted environments - you could use that to detect the end of the argument array.

Comment: If I did this, then how would I access the contents of let's say the 3rd element of my argument array?

Comment: @Mankarse has it right, you'd access it in the global exactly as you'd access `argv` within `main`. I'll add the method to the answer.

Comment: A pointer to `char *` is not the "changeable equivalent" of an array of `char *`. **Pointers and arrays are completely different things.**

Comment: I know they're completely different things, I've answered many question stating so :-) I'm talking equivalence in the sense of what you need to use to get the same effect as desired in this question, but in a way that works. Equivalence is not equality.

Answer (score 0):

orderFiles is a `const char **`, you can't modify it (the array pointer itself).

You could try assigning the array members (i.e. orderFiles[0] = argv[0] and so on).

Comment: `orderFiles` is a `char*[10]`, **not** a `const char**`. It can be implicitly converted to a `char**`, but the result of such a conversion is an prvalue, and so cannot be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a difference between arrays initialized without a length, and those initialized with one. Remove the 10 from the global variables declaration, and then it should work

The reason for this is that argv is really just a char****, but orderFiles is an array of 10 char*.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit `char**` for `orderFiles` yes, but it's constant because you initialized it to a link time allocated block of memory by specifying the size `[10]`.  You should create a non-constant `char**` or maybe `memcpy` from `argv` to your array.

Answer (score 0):

Like they all said two different data types. In other terms think of it this way: argv is an array of c-strings, and your orderFiles is declared as a single c-string.

So how to assign orderFiles depends on what you're trying to do. I typically iterate through argv to get the arguments passed to the application. Note that argv[0] is the application name.